# Unwanted redirect in admin area

Tags: wp-admin, redirect, errors, 404-error, directory

I have a strange behaviour on my backend. This is possible due to the way my WordPress is located.

I installed it in a VirtualBox, using Ubuntu from the standard repository (i.e., apt-get install wordpress). It is located in `/var/www/` as per default. The virtual mashine is mapped to a subfolder of my institution's web page. Let's call it `www.institution.com/stuff/wordpress`.

Most works fine, I can log in to the backend, create pages, etc. But, if I make changes in Settings/General and click on the "Save changes" button I get an "Error: NotFound". The changes are saved, but WordPress tries to send me to

```
www.institution.com/wp-admin/options-general.php?settings-updated=true
```

but this has to be

```
www.institution.com/stuff/wordpress/wp-admin/options-general.php?settings-updated=true
```

(`/stuff/wordpress` is missing)

Both, the "WordPress Address URL" and "Site URL" are set to "www.institution.com/stuff/wordpress". But obviously, this is not enough.

Has anybody an idea what wrong with my WordPress?

Answer (score 2):

I solved it with the help of a colleagues of mine by adding the following lines into wp-config.php:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'];
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = '/stuff/wordpress' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = '/stuff/wordpress' . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] = '/stuff/wordpress' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
```

Comment: Glad you solved your own question, please be sure to click the checkmark next your answer to indicate that your question has been resolved.